# Pyppeteer: сохранить Network.webSocketFrameReceived в словарь python

Tags: python, websocket, test-automation, puppeteer

Использую библиотеку  Pyppeteer потому что есть Chrome Dev Tools протокол и можно получить webSocketFrameReceived после отправки запроса в UI тесте. Мне удалось распечатать в терминале ответ сокета, но ето не то. Мне нужно в зависимости от статуса одного из параметров ответа (отмечен на скрине https://www.screencast.com/t/4wKSIcPjL9T) по разному продолжить мой тест. Как я могу ето сделать? Как работать с ответом сокета? сохранять ответ в словарь Python?

```
import asyncio
from pyppeteer import launch
import time
import pprint
import json


async def test():
    args = ['--start-maximized']
    browser = await launch(
        args=args,
        headless=False,
        # args=['--no-sandbox'],
        # autoClose=False
        )

    page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto('https://example.com/')
    await page.setViewport({'width': 1920, 'height': 1080})

    # create CDP Session
    cdp = await page.target.createCDPSession()
    await cdp.send('Network.enable')

    #  Login
    await page.type('input[name=login]', 'login')
    await page.type('input[name=password]', 'password')
    await page.click('button[type=submit]')
    time.sleep(2)

    # Fill in the request
    await page.type('input[name=symbol]', 'ACY')
    await page.type('input[name=quantity]', '500')
    await page.click('selector')
    await page.type('selector', 'Text')
    await page.keyboard.press('Enter')
    await page.click('button[type=submit]')

    # Waiting for the status of "Pending"
    await page.waitForSelector('selector, {'timeout': 5000})

    def printResponse(response):
        pprint.pprint(response)

    # Calls printResponse when a websocket is received
    cdp.on('Network.webSocketFrameReceived', printResponse) 

    # Calls printResponse when a websocket is sent 
    # cdp.on('Network.webSocketFrameSent', printResponse)  

    await asyncio.sleep(20)
    # await page.close()
    # await browser.close()


asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(test_best_location_accept())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 def printResponse(response):
        print(type(response))
```

отобразит тип response, это и есть словари Python